# How to multiply the matrix 3x3 by 3x1 in the language C

Tags: c

```
double s[3][3] = {-0.145, 0.784,  0.745,
                  0.214, 0.547,  0.547,
                  0.321, 0.254,  0.452 };

double g[3] = {0.124,0.245,0.657};

double result[3];

int i, j; 

int main() {
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        result[i] += s[i][j] * g[i];
        result[i];
        printf("%d\t", result[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Tell me, what is wrong I wrote in the program? As a result, you should get a matrix of 3x1.

Comment: As required by a proper [mcve], what is the output you're *expecting*, and what is the output you're *seeing*?

Comment: @DmitriyKalugin-Balashov It's global. So it is implicitly initialized to zero.

Comment: `%d` is the wrong format specifier, for one thing. And I think you want the `printf` in the outer loop, not the inner one.

Comment: The initializer for the 2D array is not written correctly.

Comment: what does this `result[i];` line do?

Comment: @KevinDTimm: Absolutely nothing. Or maybe you meant to ask what it's _meant_ to do.

Comment: Turn on all compiler warnings - save time.  I'd expect an well enabled compiler to warn about `printf("%d\t", result[i]);`.

Comment: @EugeneSh., the initializer for the 2D array has a permitted form, notwithstanding that some compilers will warn about it.  There is even [an example of such an initializer in the standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p26).

Comment: Is your result supposed to be `g` * `s` or `s` * `g`?  These will have different results, and your intent is ambiguous from the code.

Comment: @FredLarson - yes, I know that. The question is for the OP

Answer (score 2):

you need to initialize result like this:

```
double result[3] = {0.,0.,0.}
```

because `result[i] += ...`
is adding to the existing value.

and

```
result[i] += s[i][j] * g[j]; (g[j] instead of g[i])
```